# coroutine with custom timeout implementation

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio to run a subprocess that prints some output which I parse line by line and do various things based on the output I see.  I want to put a timeout on this process, but it should not be a global timeout for the life of the entire process.  Instead, whenever I see certain specific output from the process, I want to actually reset the timeout so that it starts over.  How can I implement this?

For a global timeout I have this working and it's easy, I simply call `asyncio.wait_for(_foo(), timeout)`.  But I can't get this to work with resetting the timeout.  Here's what I have so far:

```
        # here invocation is my own data structure with some bookkeeping information in it
        # (such as the start time from which I want to base my timeout decisions on).
        # and process is the value returned by await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(...)
        # _run_one_invocation() is my own function which is just a stdout readline loop
        # and some dispatching.

        # Make a Task out of the co-routine so that we decide when it gets cancelled, not Python.
        run_task = asyncio.Task(_run_one_invocation(invocation, process))
        while True:
            try:
                # Use asyncio.shield so it doesn't get cancelled if the timeout expires
                await asyncio.shield(asyncio.wait_for(run_task, 1))

                # If the await returns without raising an exception, we got to EOF and we're done.
                break
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                # If it's been too long since last reset, this is a "real" timeout.
                duration = time.time() - invocation.start_time
                if duration > timeout:
                    run_task.cancel()
                    raise
```

When I run this, the if statement which calls `run_task.cancel()` is *not* being entered, and nevertheless when I go back to the top of the loop and call `asyncio.wait_for()` again it immediately raises an `asyncio.CancelledError`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ["If a timeout occurs, it cancels the task (...) To avoid the task cancellation, wrap it in shield()."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) You must shield *the task*, not the ``wait_for``: ``await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(run_task), 1)``

Comment: Note that it is difficult to see what constitutes a valid answer for this question. Are you asking how to implement a moving timeout? Are you asking what is wrong about the code? Since all of ``invocation``, ``process``, and ``_run_one_invocation`` are basically black boxes, it is difficult to say what is going wrong as well as how to do it better. You might want to [edit] it to provide more focus, and extend the code to a [mcve].

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's my understanding that the OP wants to implement a moving timeout. He also provided his attempt to implement it, and indicated what the issue is with his implementation. While the question isn't flawless (it doesn't provide a minimal and reproducible example), it seems perfectly answerable and not deserving of being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue and simplify the code by completely avoiding `wait_for()` (and therefore `shield()`) and just using `wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` to implement the kind of timeout you need:

```
run_task = asyncio.create_task(_run_one_invocation(invocation, process))
while True:
    await asyncio.wait([run_task], timeout=1)
    if run_task.done():
        break
    if time.time() - invocation.start_time > timeout:
        run_task.cancel()
        raise asyncio.TimeoutErrror()
```

The downside of this approach is that it introduces 1s wakeups, prohibiting the program (and consequently the computer) from ever going to sleep, even if the task is dormant for hours. Probably not a big deal on a server, but such practices contribute to battery drain on laptops, and it's a good idea to avoid them. Also, the 1s sleep introduces an up to 1s latency to react to a change in timeout.

To resolve that, you can create an event that is fired by the code changing the timeout, and react to that event in addition to the timeout and the task completing:

```
timeout_changed = asyncio.Event()
# pass timeout_changed where needed, and have the code that changes
# the timeout also call timeout_changed.set()
run_task = asyncio.create_task(_run_one_invocation(invocation, process))
while True:
    remaining = timeout - (time.time() - invocation.start_time)
    timeout_changed_task = asyncio.ensure_future(timeout_changed.wait())
    await asyncio.wait([run_task, timeout_changed_task],
        return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, timeout=remaining)
    timeout_changed_task.cancel()
    # either: 1) the task has completed, 2) the previous timeout has
    # expired, or 3) the timeout has changed
    if run_task.done():
        break  # 1
    if time.time() - invocation.start_time > timeout:
        # 2 or 2+3
        run_task.cancel()
        raise asyncio.TimeoutErrror()
    # 3 - continue waiting with the new timeout
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `asyncio.sleep()`.  What is the advantage of this over using the `timeout=` keyword argument that `asyncio.wait()` accepts?

Comment: @ZacharyTurner It seemed easier to reason about the code without handling a business exception in addition to normal results. But you can certainly use it if you think it makes the code simpler.

Comment: No, I agree it does make the code cleaner and I never liked having to handle the exception.  Just wondering if there was any technical reason, and it seems like probably not.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems like I need to cancel the `asyncio.sleep()` task if it's pending when the function returns.  Otherwise I get lots of messages on shutdown about task being destroyed while it was pending.  Does this sound correct to you?  It makes the code quite a bit uglier.

Comment: @ZacharyTurner Good point, that comes from my code being untested. I guess that would be a benefit of using the `timeout` argument to `asyncio.wait()`. I now checked the docs, and `wait()` actually doesn't even bother with the `TimeoutError` (not does it cancel anything), so using `timeout` should be a no-brainer. I've now updated the answer to do so.